# Occurs error TypeError: 'Database' object is not callable" when I try connect to MongoDB from robot framwwork

Tags: mongodb, robotframework

I have installed

- pip install robotframework-mongodb-library
- pip install pymongo
- npm install mongodb

I have a testcase and import library like image [image]

But It gets error TypeError: 'Database' object is not callable". Anyone help  me?

Comment: Did robot report an import failure on stdout? Did you install the robot framework MongoDBLibrary library?

Comment: I'm tried it. I had run testcase with test case name is "connect-to-db". This is step define:
    "Connect to mongoDB    mongodb://admin:admin@foo.bar.org    10255
    ${allDBs}=    Get Mongodb Databases
    Log Many    ${allDBs}"
 But now I get another issue that is" TypeError: 'Database' object is not callable"

Comment: None of what you wrote answers my question.

Comment: ^^ Hi @BryanOakley, I answer this your question "Did you install the robot framework MongoDBLibrary library?" ----> I installed 'MongoDBLibrary' and I also install 'pymongo', 'bson'. But return error  " TypeError: 'Database' object is not callable" like as image below. Can you help me?